# Merge extremely similar Make rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile in which I create two different targets from the same files (release and debug):

```
SRCDIR:=src/
CXXFILES:=$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)*.cpp)
INC:=-Iinc/
CXXFLAGS:=-std=gnu++20 -Wshadow=local -Wall -Wfatal-errors
CPPFLAGS:=$(INC) -MMD -MP
LDFLAGS:=
ODIR:=obj/
DEBUGODIR:=$(ODIR)debug/
RELEASEODIR:=$(ODIR)release/
DEBUG_OFILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)%,$(DEBUGODIR)%,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(CXXFILES)))
RELEASE_OFILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)%,$(RELEASEODIR)%,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(CXXFILES)))
ALL_OFILES := $(DEBUG_OFILES) $(RELEASE_OFILES)
RELEASE_TARGET := final
DEBUG_TARGET := final_debug
WERROR_CONFIG := -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY: all clean debug release docs

all: release debug

release: CXXFLAGS += -O2 $(WERROR_CONFIG)
release: $(RELEASE_TARGET)

debug: CXXFLAGS += -Og -ggdb
debug: CPPFLAGS += -DDEBUG
debug: $(DEBUG_TARGET)

-include $(DEBUG_OFILES:%.o=%.d)
-include $(RELEASE_OFILES:%.o=%.d)

$(ALL_OFILES) : Makefile

$(RELEASEODIR) $(DEBUGODIR) :
    mkdir -p $@

$(RELEASE_OFILES) : | $(RELEASEODIR)
$(DEBUG_OFILES) : | $(DEBUGODIR)

$(DEBUGODIR)%.cpp.o: $(SRCDIR)%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(RELEASEODIR)%.cpp.o: $(SRCDIR)%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(DEBUG_TARGET): $(DEBUG_OFILES)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(RELEASE_TARGET): $(RELEASE_OFILES)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(ODIR)
    rm -f $(RELEASE_TARGET)
    rm -f $(DEBUG_TARGET)
```

This works fine:

```
make
mkdir -p obj/release/
mkdir -p obj/debug/
g++ -Iinc/ -MMD -MP -std=gnu++20 -Wshadow=local -Wall -Wfatal-errors -O2 -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable -c src/fraction.cpp -o obj/release/fraction.cpp.o
g++ -Iinc/ -MMD -MP -std=gnu++20 -Wshadow=local -Wall -Wfatal-errors -O2 -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable -c src/main.cpp -o obj/release/main.cpp.o
g++ -Iinc/ -MMD -MP -DDEBUG -std=gnu++20 -Wshadow=local -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Og -ggdb -c src/fraction.cpp -o obj/debug/fraction.cpp.o
g++ -Iinc/ -MMD -MP -DDEBUG -std=gnu++20 -Wshadow=local -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Og -ggdb -c src/main.cpp -o obj/debug/main.cpp.o
g++ -o final obj/release/fraction.cpp.o obj/release/main.cpp.o 
g++ -o final_debug obj/debug/fraction.cpp.o obj/debug/main.cpp.o
```

But we have some extremely similar targets, So I try to merge them

```
SRCDIR:=src/
CXXFILES:=$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)*.cpp)
INC:=-Iinc/
CXXFLAGS:=-std=gnu++20 -Wshadow=local -Wall -Wfatal-errors
CPPFLAGS:=$(INC) -MMD -MP
LDFLAGS:=
ODIR:=obj/
DEBUGODIR:=$(ODIR)debug/
RELEASEODIR:=$(ODIR)release/
DEBUG_OFILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)%,$(DEBUGODIR)%,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(CXXFILES)))
RELEASE_OFILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)%,$(RELEASEODIR)%,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.cpp.o,$(CXXFILES)))
ALL_OFILES := $(DEBUG_OFILES) $(RELEASE_OFILES)
RELEASE_TARGET := final
DEBUG_TARGET := final_debug
WERROR_CONFIG := -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY: all clean debug release docs

all: release debug

release: CXXFLAGS += -O2 $(WERROR_CONFIG)
release: $(RELEASE_TARGET)

debug: CXXFLAGS += -Og -ggdb
debug: CPPFLAGS += -DDEBUG
debug: $(DEBUG_TARGET)

-include $(DEBUG_OFILES:%.o=%.d)
-include $(RELEASE_OFILES:%.o=%.d)

$(ALL_OFILES) : Makefile

$(RELEASEODIR) $(DEBUGODIR) :
    mkdir -p $@

$(RELEASE_OFILES) : | $(RELEASEODIR)
$(DEBUG_OFILES) : | $(DEBUGODIR)

$(DEBUGODIR)%.cpp.o $(RELEASEODIR)%.cpp.o: $(SRCDIR)%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(DEBUG_TARGET): $(DEBUG_OFILES)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(RELEASE_TARGET): $(RELEASE_OFILES)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(ODIR)
    rm -f $(RELEASE_TARGET)
    rm -f $(DEBUG_TARGET)
```

And now the makefile fails completely:

```
mkdir -p obj/release/
mkdir -p obj/debug/
g++ -Iinc/ -MMD -MP -std=gnu++20 -Wshadow=local -Wall -Wfatal-errors -O2 -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable -c src/fraction.cpp -o obj/release/fraction.cpp.o
g++ -Iinc/ -MMD -MP -std=gnu++20 -Wshadow=local -Wall -Wfatal-errors -O2 -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable -c src/main.cpp -o obj/release/main.cpp.o
g++ -o final obj/release/fraction.cpp.o obj/release/main.cpp.o 
g++ -o final_debug obj/debug/fraction.cpp.o obj/debug/main.cpp.o 
/usr/sbin/ld: cannot find obj/debug/fraction.cpp.o: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/ld: cannot find obj/debug/main.cpp.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:45: final_debug] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

What am I missing here? Why does make not execute the debug rules? Running the targets independendly also gives some unexpected results:

```
make debug
mkdir -p obj/debug/
mkdir -p obj/release/
g++ -Iinc/ -MMD -MP -DDEBUG -std=gnu++20 -Wshadow=local -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Og -ggdb -c src/fraction.cpp -o obj/debug/fraction.cpp.o
g++ -Iinc/ -MMD -MP -DDEBUG -std=gnu++20 -Wshadow=local -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Og -ggdb -c src/main.cpp -o obj/debug/main.cpp.o
g++ -o final_debug obj/debug/fraction.cpp.o obj/debug/main.cpp.o
```

Why does `make debug` suddenly create `obj/release/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(DEBUGODIR)%.cpp.o $(RELEASEODIR)%.cpp.o: $(SRCDIR)%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

is a pattern rule with several targets. GNU make handles this specially: it considers that executing the recipe **once** builds **all** targets. While your recipe does not.

It used to be the only way to indicate recipes that build several targets at once. Since GNU make 4.3 there is a dedicated construct (`&:`).

There are basically two ways to do what you want: `eval` and secondary expansion. Let's start with `eval` that allows to instantiate make constructs programmatically:

```
# $(1) is the target directory
define MY_RULE
$(1)%.cpp.o: $$(SRCDIR)%.cpp
    $$(CXX) $$(CPPFLAGS) $$(CXXFLAGS) -c $$< -o $$@
endef
$(foreach d,$(DEBUGODIR) $(RELEASEODIR),$(eval $(call MY_RULE,$(d))))
```

Pay attention to the `$$` in the `MY_RULE` definition, they are needed because they will be expanded twice by make: first when expanding the arguments of `eval`, and second when parsing the result as make constructs.

Secondary expansion is another option. Every rule after the `.SECONDEXPANSION:` special target has its prerequisites list expanded twice. And during the second expansion some automatic variables are defined. So putting this at the end of your Makefile should do what you want:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(ALL_OFILES): $$(SRCDIR)/$$(patsubst %.o,%,$$(@F))
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: So, I cannot merge these targets?

Comment: You can but not like this. And not sure you will like it...